# Quote from Meseches Shabbos

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara, maseches-shabbos

I saw a quote in *Meseches Shabbos* that said, *"If you want to do good, Hashem will help you accomplish it."*

Does anyone know where in that *Gemara* I can find it?

Comment: If you like an answer, consider marking it correct.

Answer (score 3):

The Gemara Shabbos (104a) says: בא ליטמא פותחין לו בא ליטהר מסייעים אותו

Translation: "If one comes to become impure [i.e. sin] they [i.e. heavenly forces] open (the way) for him. If one comes to become pure they [i.e. heavenly forces] help him"

Comment: Does my translation fit the words?

Comment: @ChiddusheiTorah your quote seems like a fine paraphrase of the text.

Comment: Your translation seems a lot better than mine.